# How the WHERE clause works on Partitioning by Range?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

My database is on AWS RDS and getting bigger day by day. 
The reason for it is we have several cron jobs that fetches data through various API's and add it into our database. The data is increasing and affecting the SQL *SEARCH* operations.
I am thinking of archiving the previous year's data so that the WHERE clause keeps running without any latency and it does not traverse the complete record set (the previous years data).

I came to know recently about MYSQL Partitioning concept and by using the RANGE filter, we can partition the data of each year. My only concern about is if I have columns in the table like:-
`id, first_name, last_name, email, created_date`

and the partitioning is done as:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(created_date)) ( 
          PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2019), 
          PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2020), 
          PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE  
    )
```

If I run the SQL query as:

```
select * from table where email = "abc@....com"
```

**Here, the partition is created on column *created_date* but WHERE clause is applied on *email* column so from which partition it will fetch the result?**

Comment: From all, of course. Except the case when you hint to use only separate partition(s).

Comment: @Akina If it searches from both partitions, then I don't think partitions will be helpful during such cases because the number of records will remain the same. Isn't it?

Comment: That's true. Partitioning cannot improve all queries.

Comment: @I.Sharma . . . Partitioning only improves performance when the query is filtering on the partitioning key.